# How to dense rank within a group with a sum limit?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to `group by` code and `rank` but with a condition that if the sum of container exceeds 2000 it should be put in next group. Can this be achieved in Pandas?

I have the following data:

```
+---+----------+--+------------------+
| 1 | Load No. |  |  Code  Weight    |
| 2 | 1        |  |  4000   200      |
| 3 | 2        |  |  4000  1800      |
| 4 | 3        |  |  4000   400      |
| 5 | 4        |  |  4000   1000     |
| 6 | 5        |  |  5000   1000     |
| 7 | 6        |  |  5000   800      |
| 8 | 7        |  |  5000   1200     |
+---+----------+--+------------------+
```

Output:

```
| 1 | Load No. | Code  Weight Container Total Sum 
| 2 | 1        | 4000   200     1         2000 
| 3 | 2        | 4000   1800    1         2000 
| 4 | 3        | 4000   400     2         1400 
| 5 | 4        | 4000   1000    2         1400 
| 6 | 5        | 5000   1000    3         1800 
| 7 | 6        | 5000   800     3         1800 
| 8 | 7        | 5000   1200    4         1200
```

Comment: Most people want to see text not image formatted, you can use [this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for formatted table.. And of SO are not free code service.. *I want* are not good statement.. Show your effort..

Comment: I am pretty new to this. Will edit this one in the formatted table. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method for get the `Container`

```
s=df.Weight.cumsum()/2000
pd.cut(s,np.arange(0,max(s)+1,1)).cat.codes+1
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
dtype: int8
df['container']=pd.cut(s,np.arange(0,max(s)+1,1)).cat.codes+1
```

Then we using `transform`

```
df['total sum']=df.groupby('container').Weight.transform('sum')
df
   LoadNo.  Code  Weight  container  total sum
0        1  4000     200          1       2000
1        2  4000    1800          1       2000
2        3  4000     400          2       1400
3        4  4000    1000          2       1400
4        5  5000    1000          3       1800
5        6  5000     800          3       1800
6        7  5000    1200          4       1200
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wanted to understand how to initially group by code and then calculate the weight and make containers?

Comment: @EashanBhattacharyya make the first step as an function , then group by apply the function

Comment: Thanks for your help @W-B . Can you guide me a little more. I am confused with how to implement the function.

I made a function like this :

def added_weight():
    s=data.ITEM_WEIGHT.cumsum()/2000
    container=pd.cut(s,np.arange(0,max(s)+1,1)).cat.codes+1
    return container

data['container']= data.groupby('code')['Weight'].apply(added_weight(),axis=1)